# why is the ripple emulator giving me this error message?

Tags: html, blackberry, blackberry-webworks, ripple

I just installed the Ripple Emulator and the BlackBerry WebWorks SDK. However, when I start up the Ripple Emulator, it goes straight to a page that says, "404 page not found" but I only just started it up.

Answer (score 0):

This is same problem i was faced ... make sure you have deleted the backup of Ripple Emulator (folder in installation path) if you have previously installed and now you are going to reinstall it. Some times it behaves abnormally so you have to delete all the footprints of previous installation.